# OpenCV line extrapolation to nearest edge

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to extract tabular data from a pdf with irregularly shaped tables.

Some of the lines of a given table could be obstructed and fail to fully delineate and enclose cells;
however, incomplete segments are left behind.

Can I extrapolate these up to the nearest edge?

See below

Thanks

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: instead of fixing a mistake, prevent it. show source data. [mre]

Comment: It seems that, when you found endpoint of line, what to do is basically, stretching the line pixel by pixel to reach to some other line.
If so, your main problem will be endpoint detection. Therefore I recommend to consider to try some line detection or corner detection like process to detect the endpoints at first. If you already have some trying, you should show the trying result.

Comment: And, Maybe, some explicit definition of the condition helps your try (and/or answer by someone). e.g. maximum of line thickness, minimum size of grid rectangle, actual direction of lines, etc.

Comment: are you saying you _don't have_ the source data, just those pictures? why is that?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for your patience. I've had virtually only bad experiences whenever I've posted questions and may have overreacted to your response in particular. That said, while I was trying to remove all the sensitive data from the source material to be able to post it, I noticed the pdfs are not flattened, and that the signature is actually an overlay. What I've done instead of this, then, is to use PyPDF2.PdfWriter.remove_links() which prevents this gap from being created in the first place.

Comment: @fana thanks for your responses. I wrote in the comment above to Christoph that I discovered, trying to clean the data to post it here, that the PDFs are not flattened, and that the signatures are overlays that can be easily removed with the PyPDF2.PdfWriter.remove_links() method. But I was trying to ask about a solution for endpoint detection, and couldn't figure anything out on my own. That said, I'm still very curious to know what a solution might look like, if I haven't wasted too much of your time already. Grid size is variable, direction always x or y, line thickness as required.

Comment: here is the result of extending those line stubs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXYKq.png -- requires a little bit of `cv.filter2D()` to count neighbors (3x3 kernel with center blank, rest 1) and to find points with one neighbor (end of a line). then you'd figure out where the neighbor is, and extend the line in the other direction until you hit another line (non-blank pixel).

Comment: I'll post a solution in a bit. In Python.

Comment: say, what language do you need this in anyway? this does NOT require 105 lines of code.

Comment: Sorry I've been assigned to other projects this week. But I'm working in python

Answer (score 2):

I commented :

> It seems that, when you found endpoint of line, what to do is basically, stretching the line pixel by pixel to reach to some other line.

and you said:

> But I was trying to ask about a solution for endpoint detection, and couldn't figure anything out on my own.

So, I show the process of finding the endpoints.
Following C++ code is only the endpoint finding part (not include stretching part).

what doing is very very simple.

1. Find horizontal line segments
2. Find vertical line segments
3. If an endpoint of horizonal lineseg is not locating on any vertical lineseg, this endpoint is judged to have to be extend.
4. Samely, If an endpoint of vertical lineseg is not locating on any horizontal lineseg, this endpoint is judged to have to be extend.

```cpp
//Line segment data : just has 2 endpoint location.
struct LineSeg
{
    cv::Point EndPoint[2];

    LineSeg() = default;
    LineSeg( const cv::Point &EP1, const cv::Point &EP2 ) : EndPoint{ EP1, EP2 } {}
    const cv::Point &operator[]( int idx ) const {  return EndPoint[idx];   }
};

//* This implementation requires that alll pixels in rightmost column to be white.
void FindHorizontalBlackLines( const cv::Mat &BinImg, std::vector<LineSeg> &DstHLines )
{
    //Simply checking pixel by pixel, from left to right.
    for( int y=0; y<BinImg.rows; ++y )
    {
        const unsigned char *p = BinImg.ptr<unsigned char>( y );
        cv::Point LeftEP{ -1, y };  //x<0 indicates the state "left side endpoint is not found yet".
        for( int x=0; x<BinImg.cols; ++x, ++p )
        {
            if( LeftEP.x < 0 )
            {
                if( *p == 0 ){  LeftEP.x = x;   }
            }
            else
            {
                if( *p != 0 )
                {
                    if( x - LeftEP.x >= 5 ){    DstHLines.emplace_back( LeftEP, cv::Point(x-1,y) ); }
                    LeftEP.x = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Find EndPoints of the "Candidates" that are not on the LineSeg group "OtherDirectionalLineSegs"
void DecideEndPointsToExtend(
    const std::vector<LineSeg> &Candidates,
    const std::vector<LineSeg> &OtherDirectionalLineSegs,
    cv::Mat EnoughSizeBuffer,  //8bit 1ch
    std::vector< cv::Point > &DstPoints
)
{
    EnoughSizeBuffer = 0;
    for( const auto &L : OtherDirectionalLineSegs )
    {   cv::line( EnoughSizeBuffer, L[0],L[1], cv::Scalar(255) );   }

    for( const auto &C : Candidates )
    {
        for( const auto &EP : C.EndPoint )
        {
            if( EnoughSizeBuffer.at<unsigned char>( EP ) == 0 )
            {   DstPoints.push_back( EP );  }
        }
    }
}

//main
int main()
{
    cv::Mat SrcImg = cv::imread( "Grid.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( SrcImg.empty() )return 0;

    cv::Mat BinImg;
    cv::threshold(
        SrcImg, BinImg,
        200,    //* Here, this threshold value cause "bold" black lines for the your image.
        255, cv::THRESH_BINARY
    );

    //Here, I added white border to image
    //to meet to the requirement of my function FindHorizontalBlackLines() above.
    //( and also for visibility )
    constexpr int BorderTheckness=10;
    cv::copyMakeBorder( BinImg, BinImg, BorderTheckness,BorderTheckness,BorderTheckness,BorderTheckness, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar(255) );

    //Find Horizontal LineSegs
    std::vector< LineSeg > HLines;
    FindHorizontalBlackLines( BinImg, HLines );

    //Find Vertical LineSegs
    std::vector< LineSeg > VLines;
    {
        cv::Mat WorkImg;
        cv::rotate( BinImg, WorkImg, cv::ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE );
        cv::imshow( "Work", WorkImg );
        FindHorizontalBlackLines( WorkImg, VLines );

        for( auto &L : VLines )
        {
            for( auto &EP : L.EndPoint )
            {
                std::swap( EP.x, EP.y );
                EP.y = WorkImg.cols-1 - EP.y;
            }
        }
    }

    //Find result points
    std::vector<cv::Point> PointsToExtend;
    {
        cv::Mat WorkBuff( BinImg.size(), CV_8UC1 );
        DecideEndPointsToExtend( HLines, VLines, WorkBuff, PointsToExtend );
        DecideEndPointsToExtend( VLines, HLines, WorkBuff, PointsToExtend );

        //Remove points locate on the border of SrcImg
        auto SrcSize = SrcImg.size();
        PointsToExtend.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                PointsToExtend.begin(), PointsToExtend.end(),
                [SrcSize, BorderTheckness]( const cv::Point &P )->bool
                {
                    int Xs = P.x - BorderTheckness;
                    int Ys = P.y - BorderTheckness;
                    return ( Xs <= 0 ) || ( Xs >= SrcSize.width-1 ) || ( Ys <= 0 ) || ( Ys >= SrcSize.height-1 );
                }
            ),
            PointsToExtend.end()
        );
    }

    //Visualize
    cv::Mat ShowImg = cv::Mat::zeros( BinImg.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    for( const auto &HLine : HLines ){  cv::line( ShowImg, HLine[0],HLine[1], cv::Scalar(255,0,0) );    }
    for( const auto &VLine : VLines ){  cv::line( ShowImg, VLine[0],VLine[1], cv::Scalar(0,160,0) );    }
    for( const auto &P : PointsToExtend ){  ShowImg.at< cv::Vec3b >( P ) = cv::Vec3b(255,255,255);  }
    cv::imshow( "Result", ShowImg );
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is drawn in units of pixels, so it is difficult to see, but the points found are drawn in white.
(For bold lines, end point becomes multiple pixels)
[image]

Comment: thanks @fana. I haven't been able to look at this in depth yet, but I've taken a note to take a look later